# pip installation error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, time-series

Facebook just released Prophet a Time Series library for both R and Python. Installation depends upon Cython and PyStan which were installed using pip (Cython was already there). PyStand installed successfully though I got "Failed to build pystan". 
When I do a pip install fbprophet, I get the following error :

```
Collecting fbprophet
Using cached fbprophet-0.1.post1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in dist
ribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in dis
tribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in dis
tribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.png' found anywhere in dis
tribution
no previously-included directories found matching 'pystan\stan\make'
no previously-included directories found matching 'pystan\stan\src\docs'
no previously-included directories found matching 'pystan\stan\src\doxygen'
no previously-included directories found matching 'pystan\stan\src\python'
no previously-included directories found matching 'pystan\stan\src\test'
no previously-included directories found matching 'pystan\stan\lib\stan_math
\doxygen'
no previously-included directories found matching 'pystan\stan\lib\stan_math
\make'
no previously-included directories found matching 'pystan\stan\lib\stan_math
\test'
no previously-included directories found matching 'pystan\stan\lib\stan_math
\lib\cpplint_4.45'
no previously-included directories found matching 'pystan\stan\lib\stan_math
\lib\gtest_1.7.0'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\polest~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-rnvpe9\fbprophet\setu
p.py", line 96, in <module>
    """
  File "C:\Users\PolestarEmployee\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\core.py", line 111
, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "C:\Users\PolestarEmployee\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.
3-py2.7.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 269, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\PolestarEmployee\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.
3-py2.7.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
  File "C:\Users\PolestarEmployee\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.
3-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 827, in resolve
  File "C:\Users\PolestarEmployee\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.
3-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1072, in best_match
  File "C:\Users\PolestarEmployee\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.
3-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1084, in obtain
  File "C:\Users\PolestarEmployee\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.
3-py2.7.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
  File "C:\Users\PolestarEmployee\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.
3-py2.7.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 640, in easy_install
  File "C:\Users\PolestarEmployee\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.
3-py2.7.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 670, in install_item
  File "C:\Users\PolestarEmployee\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.
3-py2.7.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 850, in install_eggs
  File "C:\Users\PolestarEmployee\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.
3-py2.7.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1078, in   
build_and_install
  File "C:\Users\PolestarEmployee\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.
3-py2.7.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1066, in run_setup
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error:     

SandboxViol
ation: open('build\\lib.win-amd64-   
2.7\\pystan\\stan\\lib\\stan_math_2.14.0\\doc\
\api\\html\\d0\\d0f\\   
structstan_1_1is__vector__like_3_01_eigen_1_1_matrix_3_01_t
_00_01_eigen_1_1_dynamic_00_01_eigen_1_1_dynamic_01_4_01_4-members.html',   
'wb')
{} 

The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.

This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.
```

Is it somehow connected to "Failed to build pystan", even though cmd says "successfully installed pystan".

Comment: Well, if you failed to build `pystan`, this means it _wasn't_ installed successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you need to install pystan (`pip install pystan`) separately.

From the facebook [installation instructions.](https://facebookincubator.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html)

> The major dependency that Prophet has is pystan. PyStan has its own installation instructions.

Comment: Ok got it now why it isn't working. For pystan, python 3.5 or higher is needed. I was using 2.7 :(

Comment: Not sure about that. I'm relatively certain that pystan works on 2.7. Have you made sure your `pip` and `setuptools` are up to date?

Comment: Yes they are up to date. Actually I am working on windows.
This is in pystan documentation for windows:
"PyStan is supported under Windows with the following caveats:

Python 3.5 or higher must be used.
When drawing samples n_jobs=1 must be used. (PyStan on Windows cannot use multiple processors in parallel.)
"

Comment: Good luck! Pystan on windows is extremely painful (I spent a couple of days working on it before moving over to py 3.5 and pip installing it).

Answer (score 0):

`pip install cython` then `pip install pystan` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Beneficial from the post at https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan/issues/306

I have met various error message, but finally, I install PyStan successfully. Then, just use the command: pip install fbprophet, and fbprophet can be installed.

My machine is on Windows 7, x64 with Anaconda3 installed.Here are the procedures to install PyStan from the sourced codes.

1. Install Visual Studio 2017 & Visual Studio C++ Build Tool 2015 at http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
2. Update Conda

conda update conda

conda update --all

3. check the dependencies

pip install setuptool

conda install numpy cython matplotlib scipy pandas

4. Install gcc compiler components

conda install libpython

conda install -c msys2 m2w64-toolchain=5.3.0

5. created distutils.cfg file inside Anaconda3\Lib\distutils folder with the following:

[build]

compiler = mingw32

6. Download Git at https://git-scm.com/downloads

git clone --recursive https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan.git

7. Compile from the source code

python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32

python setup.py install

P.S. The solution for the issue: Cannot build msvcr library: "vcruntime140d.dll" not found.

Copy vcruntime140d.dll from C:\Windows\System32 to any folder, which is reachable in the path in the advanced system settings/environment variables/ system variables.